# Get day of date string with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I cant find a way of getting the day from a date string. The format of the string is `dd/mm/yyyy` and I want to use getDay() to get the current weekday.

Is this possible? I know i'd have to convert my string to a `Date` object but cant find a list of accepted formats

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Date.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Comment: _"I know I'd have to convert my string to a Date object"_. Eh, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, problems are a lot simpler than they seem.

```
var date = "16/06/2014";
var dayOfDate = date.substr(0,2);
```

If a single-digit day is possible, try this:

```
var date = "5/6/2014";
var parts = date.split("/");
var dayOfDate = parts[0];
```

---

And sometimes, it pays to read the question >_>

Continuing from the second option above:

```
var dateObj = new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
// parts[1]-1 because months are zero-based
var dayOfWeek = dateObj.getDay();
```

Comment: OP wants the day (0-6), not the date.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`Date.prototype.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) doesn't seem to support that format. I would write a `parseDate()`,

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('/');
  // Note: months are 0-based
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
}
function getName(day) {
    if (day == 0) return 'Sunday';
    else if (day == 1) return 'Monday';
    else if (day == 2) return 'Tuesday';
    else if (day == 3) return 'Wednesday';
    else if (day == 4) return 'Thursday';
    else if (day == 5) return 'Friday';
    return 'Saturday';
}
var d = parseDate('16/06/2014');
var weekday = d.getDay();
var weekdayName = getName(weekday);
```

and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ElliottFrisch/ft6PH/1/).

Comment: `getName` could be much simpler as `return ["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","Satur"][day]+"day";`